# LWJGL Speed Rendering up

Tags: java, performance, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL to create sort of a Minecraft Clone.

The problem is that i only get about 20 FPS. (with about 32 blocks in each direction)
Also when i change the chunk the view freezes for some milliseconds.

I'm loading the textures with Slick. To render the blocks I use VBOs for textures and vertices (no VAOs or Shaders or normals). Each block consists of 6 quads which consist out of 2 triangles. Faces between blocks aren't rendered. Every frame the rendering thread checks for all 32 * 32 chunks if they are loaded into a buffer and if they should be loaded (depending on player position). If they are needed the vbos are created and the handles are saved to a list. If the chunks are too far away, the buffers get deleted. While rendering, all vbos currently in the graphics cards ram (handles saved in list) are drawn.

How can i speed rendering up? Should i have the buffers in "loaded" all the time and draw only the objects needed? Can normals or VAOs or shaders help me get a drastic improvement? Still if i get the frame rate higher there will be mor blocks than just a plate and i'm planning to import .obj.

Minecraft renders in i think DisplayLists. Would that be a solution? Create a display list for every chunk or block and recompile them if block or chunk changes?

Edit: I measured with VisualVM that the most time consuming method is glDrawArrays().

Some source code:

Rendering:

```
public static void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    for(VBO vbo : vbos)
    {
        //disable texture smoothing
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, vbo.texture);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo.vertex_handle);
        glVertexPointer(vbo.vertex_size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo.texture_handle);
        glTexCoordPointer(vbo.texture_size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vbo.vertices);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

Chunk loading detection:

```
int chunkX = (int)(camera.getX() * (-1) / GameData.CHUNK_SIZE);
        int chunkZ = (int)(camera.getZ() * (-1) / GameData.CHUNK_SIZE);

        for(int cx = 0;cx < GameData.NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS;cx++)
        {
            for(int cz = 0;cz < GameData.NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS;cz++)
            {
                boolean shouldBeLoaded = (Math.abs(chunkX - cx) <= 2 && Math.abs(chunkZ - cz) <= 2);

                if(GameData.chunks[cx][cz] != shouldBeLoaded)
                {
                    if(shouldBeLoaded)
                        Util.loadChunk(cx, cz);//loads every block in the chunk
                    else
                        Util.unloadChunk(cx, cz);
                }
            }
        }
```

Block loading:

```
public void load()
{
    try{
        if(GameData.map[x][y+1][z] == null || GameData.map[x][y+1][z].id == 2)
            top = Util.createQuad(x, y+1, z, 1, id);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){};

    try{
        if(GameData.map[x][y-1][z] == null || GameData.map[x][y-1][z].id == 2)
            bot = Util.createQuad(x, y, z, 1, id);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){};

    try{
        if(GameData.map[x-1][y][z] == null || GameData.map[x-1][y][z].id == 2)
            left = Util.createQuad(x, y, z, 0, id);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){};

    try{
        if(GameData.map[x+1][y][z] == null || GameData.map[x+1][y][z].id == 2)
            right = Util.createQuad(x+1, y, z, 0, id);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){};

    try{
        if(GameData.map[x][y][z-1] == null || GameData.map[x][y][z-1].id == 2)
            front = Util.createQuad(x, y, z, 2, id);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){};

    try{
        if(GameData.map[x][y][z+1] == null || GameData.map[x][y][z+1].id == 2)
            back = Util.createQuad(x, y, z+1, 2, id);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){};
}
```

Util.createQuad()

```
public static VBO createQuad(float x, float y, float z, int axis, int id)
{
    boolean xA = axis == 0;
    boolean yA = axis == 1;//senkrecht
    boolean zA = axis == 2;

    FloatBuffer vertex_data = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6 * 3);
    if(xA)
    {
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z+1, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y+1, z+1, });

        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y+1, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y+1, z+1, });
    }
    if(yA)
    {
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z+1, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x+1, y, z+1, });

        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x+1, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x+1, y, z+1, });
    }
    if(zA)
    {
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x+1, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x+1, y+1, z, });

        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x, y+1, z, });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { x+1, y+1, z, });
    }

    FloatBuffer texture_data = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6 * 2);
    texture_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, });
    texture_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 0f, });
    texture_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 1f, });

    texture_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, });
    texture_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 1f, });
    texture_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 1f, });


    vertex_data.flip();
    texture_data.flip();

    int vbo_vertex_handle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex_handle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    int vbo_texture_handle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_texture_handle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    VBO vbo = new VBO(vbo_vertex_handle, vbo_texture_handle, renderEngine.textures.get(id), 6, 3, 2);

    if(id == 2)//transparent
        renderEngine.vbos.add(vbo);
    else
        renderEngine.vbos.add(0, vbo);;

    return vbo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using display lists because I'm still new to lwjgl and found VBO's pretty confusing, What I do is only check if the player moved 16 blocks or more, or removed/placed a block And that's when I update my lists, Otherwise I don't update the lists, You should also stop rendering any faces that you cannot see, So while checking for which faces to draw, You should also check if they are not in your view range, Here's an example of what I do; This example checks if I should render the top face of a certain block: if(PlayerY < BlockY) { then return false; }, This way you don't need to render something that you probably can't see.

Using display lists I get around 200 - 300 FPS for a view range of 48*48, At 128 you would get around 20 - 100 FPS.
EDIT:
You should also start using a texture atlas if you're not already, That reduces the bind() calls, Which makes it SO MUCH faster.

So good luck, And hope I helped :)